# generic operation for both normal variable and const variable

Tags: c++, pointers

In the following code, is there a way to make `extint *smaller` point to both variables of `extint` type and `const extint` type?

```
extint extint::operator+ (const extint &b)
{
    extint result;
    int sum;
    extint* smaller = (num.size() < b.num.size()) ? this : &b;

    //do stuff

    return result;
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: I wonder why `operator +` doesn't take 2 `const extint`. I mean, why `this` is not `const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common type is `const extint*`, so you may do

```
const extint* smaller = (num.size() < b.num.size()) ? this : &b;
```

(but then you can't modify smaller, even for `this`).

Comment: Im a new programmer so I may be doing something totally nooby here. I have no idea. Basically I overloaded the operator as part of a class that defines an integer that can take any size. In this function basically I intend to add two of the integers that can take any size. I checked out this syntax online. I only need to pass one of the integers. in the online example it was being passed as a constant. i thought doing that was important. Also will const extint* take an int? thanks for the help!

Comment: kindly explain the concept of common type. how is const extint more "common" than simply extint?

Comment: @dmbhatti: you can do `const extint* const_ptr = no_const_ptr;` but not `extint* no_const_ptr = const_ptr;`. That why `const extint*` is *more common* than `extint*`.